# Python can't match word at the of of the string(regex module)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.6

I have the following code:

```
p = re.compile(ur'(.{0,20})\b(\d{2,4})[^\d]{1,5}(\d{3,4})[^\d]{1,5}(\d{4,6})\b(.{0,20})', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"223-356-7890 asdasdasdas dfgdfgdf"

print re.match(p, test_str)
```

It matches the 223-356-7890 good, but when the line is `"asdasdasdas dfgdfgdf 223-356-7890"` it doesn't match anything. What's the problem ?
I tried http://regex101.com/ , and it matches but not in my python

Comment: try this `(.{0,21})\b(\d{2,4})[^\d]{1,5}(\d{3,4})[^\d]{1,5}(\d{4,6})\b(.{0,20})` regex.

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to be?

Comment: I want it just to match

Comment: What @JonClements means is that if you provide us with your expected output, the regex could possibly be made simpler and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your example you have 21 characters before the sequence of numbers:

```
  re.match(ur"(.{0,20})\b(\d{2,4})[^\d]{1,5}(\d{3,4})[^\d]{1,5}\b(.{0,20})",
  "asdasdasdas dfgdfgdf 223-356-7890")
```

results in no match but

```
  re.match(ur"(.{0,21})\b(\d{2,4})[^\d]{1,5}(\d{3,4})[^\d]{1,5}\b(.{0,20})",
  "asdasdasdas dfgdfgdf 223-356-7890")
```

matches. This is because you require maximum of 20 characters in first option which is not able to match.  On regex101: http://regex101.com/r/fN3zU5/27 you can see that for the second example the first character does not match which results in a mismatch for python.

a more flexible solution might be
 `(.*?)(\d{2,4})[^\d]{1,5}(\d{3,4})[^\d]{1,5}(\d{4,6})(.*)`
see http://regex101.com/r/fN3zU5/28

or if you are not interested in the remaining string after you found your number sequence you can use:
`(.*?)(\d{2,4})[^\d]{1,5}(\d{3,4})[^\d]{1,5}(\d{4,6})(.*?)`

Like on: http://regex101.com/r/fN3zU5/29